# onEach changes the dispatcher in StateFlow (kotlin coroutines)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Imagine the following self-contained test case

```
@Test
fun `stateFlow in GlobalScope`() = runBlockingTest {

    suspend fun makeHeavyRequest(): String {
        return "heavy result"
    }

    val flow1 = flowOf(Unit)
        .map { makeHeavyRequest() }
        .onEach { logThread("1: before flowOn") }
        .flowOn(testDispatcher)
        .stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, "init state")

    val flow2 = flowOf(Unit)
        .map { makeHeavyRequest() }
        .onEach { logThread("2: before flowOn") }
        .flowOn(testDispatcher)
        .stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, "init state")
        .onEach { logThread("2: after stateIn") }

    val flow3 = flowOf(Unit)
        .map { makeHeavyRequest() }
        .onEach { logThread("3: before flowOn") }
        .flowOn(testDispatcher)
        .onEach { logThread("3: after flowOn") }
        .stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, "init state")

    flow1.test {
        assertEquals("heavy result", expectItem())
        cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
    }

    flow2.test {
        assertEquals("heavy result", expectItem())
        cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
    }

    flow3.test {
        assertEquals("heavy result", expectItem())
        cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
    }

}
```

The effect of running it will be:

```
Thread (1: before flowOn): Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]
Thread (2: before flowOn): Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]
Thread (2: after stateIn): Thread[main @coroutine#6,5,main]
Thread (3: before flowOn): Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#8,5,main]
Thread (3: after flowOn): Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#4,5,main]


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :heavy result
Actual   :init state
```

**In `flow3` placing the `onEach` between `flowOn` and `stateIn` completely changes the dispatcher and messes up the result. Why is that?**

Comment: could you share your `Flow.test` implementation (or if its a dependency, which one).

Comment: It's Turbine by square, but when I use the standard approach with collecting items in some list and then cancelling the hot flowable, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `stateIn` operator has some optimizations depending on whether the upstream flow is a `ChannelFlow`. 
`.flowOn(...)` returns a `ChannelFlow` while `.onEach(...)` does not.

Usually this would not really matter. Why it does matter in your case, is because you expect the flow returned by `stateIn` to never emit the initial value. But there is a reason this parameter is mandatory and you should expect to receive the initial value. Whether you actually do mostly depends on whether the upstream flow is able to emit a value without suspending.

Now it appears that the one of the optimizations in the `stateIn` operator is, that it might consume a ChannelFlow without suspending. Thats why you get your expected behavior when using

```
.flowOn(testDispatcher) /*returns ChannelFlow*/
.stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, "init state")
```

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Let me clarify one thing. I was surprised that I don't get the "init state" in test scenarios. You say "Whether you actually do mostly depends on whether the upstream flow is able to emit a value without suspending." - if I, e.g. put `delay()` in my `makeHeavyRequest()` I would get both the "init state" and "heavy result"?

Comment: Okay, I just checked it. And it works just like you said, I just needed to `testDispatcher.advanceTimeBy`. To be honest this behavior is a bit weird to me (coming from rxjava world and looking for BehaviorProcessor analogues).

Comment: Just one more thing - I get that there's some optimization around ChannelFlow. But isn't that ultimately a bug? Do you think I should report it?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, more of a behavior that could be better documented. Usually when using stateflow, you want to operate on the most recent value anyways, so why keep the initial value, which is probably just a placeholder, if the flow has already emitted a value

Answer (score 3):

You should use `MainScope` instead of `GlobalScope`.
`Global Scope` is an uncontrolled scope.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope.html

You can find more good patterns in coroutines:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad

Comment: Indeed, changing the scope to something that I can control and changing its dispatcher to testDispatcher, does fix the test case. Thank you!