# StateFlow tied to application's lifetime, but without GlobalScope (Android, coroutines)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the coroutine world, `GlobalScope` seems to be highly discouraged. I, myself run into lots of issues with it, most notably in unit testing (e.g. [onEach changes the dispatcher in StateFlow (kotlin coroutines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823459/oneach-changes-the-dispatcher-in-stateflow-kotlin-coroutines)).

Anyway, I wonder **what I could use instead** for some StateFlows which should generally live longer than the lifetime of a single viewmodel etc. Consider some singleton respository the keeps some state for use by different viewmodels (UDF-style). It should keep that state throughout the app's lifetime. Something like this:

```
class CartManager(
    private val cartService: CartService,
    dispatchers: DispatcherProvider
) {

    private val cartRefreshChannel = Channel<Unit>()

    val cartFlow = cartRefreshChannel
        .receiveAsFlow()
        .conflate()
        .onStart { emit(Unit) }
        .map { cartService.requestCart() }
        .flowOn(dispatchers.io())
        .stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), null)

    suspend fun addItemToCart() {
        cartService.addItemToCart()
        cartRefreshChannel.send(Unit)
    }

    //there should be some error handling and retrying here, generally the cartFlow should never cancel / fail

}
```

What I could use here instead of GlobalScope to keep the same functionality but not be bothered with `GlobalScope` quirks?

Comment: [LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner).lifecycleScope:androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleCoroutineScope), every activity, fragment (i.e. with a lifecycle) is itself a LifecycleOwner.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but these scopes are short-lived. The point is that I want the CartManager and its state to be shared among mutiple activites/fragments/viewmodels which will be created and destroyed at different times.

Comment: oh, then you can use `MainScope` (basically returns a new `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main` without any parent job attached).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `MainScope` stored in Application class instead of `GlobalScope`

```
class MyApplication {
   val applicationScope = MainScope()
}
```

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope.html